# Рекурсивные запросы, списки смежности

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть таблица хранящая  вершины  в виде списков смежностей

```
Keyword(id INT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT, parent_id INT REFERENCES Keyword DEFAULT NULL);
```

нужно посчитать для каждой вершины размер ее поддерева
т.е. для данных

```
id  parent_id             
------------- 
0   NULL      
1   0         
2   0         
3   1         
4   1
```

будет

```
 id  size
-------------
   0   5
   1   3
   2   1
   3   1
   4   1
```

по идеи можно  пройти  по списку смежности, с использованием массива, который хранит путь потом  используя операнды @> или <@ посчитать размер поддерева.

Т.е. есть пути `0-1-3, 1-3, 0-8, 0-1-4, 1-4`

и для `0` размер будет `5`

не пойму как для каждого узла хранить масив определяющий путь без использования функций

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (
  select id,id as idx
    from Keyword
  union all
  select K.id,q.idx as idx
    from Keyword K, q
   where K.parent_id=q.id
)
select idx,count(1) from q
 group by idx
 order by idx
```

Вот так в postresql выглядят рекурсивные запросы. Внутри `RECURSIVE` всегда должен быть `union`. Первая часть `union` должна выбрать стартовые записи, с которых рекурсия начнется. Например, если бы нам надо было посчитать не количество потомков, а получить всех потомков записи с id=0 мы бы в первой части задали условие `where id=0`. Вторая часть `union` это основная рекурсивная часть. Она осуществляет спуск по дереву, выбирая записи из `with` и при этом поставляя собственные выбранные записи в этот же `with`, после чего она их там видит и использует уже их id. Что бы правильно посчитать записи нам надо знать изначальный id с которого начала выбираться ветвь, для этого приходится в первом подзапросе выбрать id второй раз и назвать его по другому, потому как просто q.id равен parent.id и у потомка это будет id его непосредственного родителя. А выбрав id под другим именем, не указанным в where мы получаем именно изначального родителя.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю вы рекурсию собираетесь от корня вести, попробуйте наоборот. От листьев к корню:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d786/2)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tree
    ("id" int, "parent_id" int)
;

INSERT INTO tree
    ("id", "parent_id")
VALUES
    (0, NULL),
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH RECURSIVE go_up(id, parent_id) as (
  select id, parent_id
  from tree
  union all
  select tree.id, tree.parent_id
  from go_up join tree on tree.id=go_up.parent_id
  )
select id, count(*) from go_up
group by id
order by id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d786/2/0)**:

```
| id | count |
|----|-------|
|  0 |     5 |
|  1 |     3 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |
|  4 |     1 |
```