# Подсчет итогов в таблицах со связью предок-потомок

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос-в-запросе

**Возникли трудности с написанием запроса для подсчета итогов по этапам (договорам) по каждому подразжелению (IdStructure) соответствующего уровня вложенности (Level) (т.е. при уровне вложенности 0 - по всей организации, 1 - по всем управлениям, 2 - по всем отделам).**

**Это все мытарство можно объединить в одном запросе/представлении для вывода на форму (далее в отчет exel)? Прошу помочь или подтолкнуть в нужном направлении**

Связь таблиц реализована следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже прикрепляю таблицу с запросом, которые данные необходимо просуммировать (**dbo.View_BalanceStage**):

```
SELECT        s.IdStage, s.IdContract, s.NumberOfStage, s.Status, s.StartDate, s.EndDate, s.PriceWithTax, s.PriceNotTaxable, s.Tax, s.PriceWithoutTax, s.TravelCosts, s.MaterialCosts, s.OtherDirectCosts, s.CommentOtherCosts, 
                     SumExe.SumOutsideExec, SumExe.SumNotTaxableOutsideExec, SumExe.SumWithoutTaxOutsideExec, SumExe.SumTaxOutsideExec, SumExe.SumInsideExec, SumExe.SumNotTaxableInsideExec, 
                     SumExe.SumWithoutTaxInsideExec, SumExe.SumTaxInsideExec, ISNULL(SumExe.SumInsideExec + SumExe.SumOutsideExec, 0) AS SumAllExec, 
                     ISNULL(SumExe.SumNotTaxableInsideExec + SumExe.SumNotTaxableOutsideExec, 0) AS SumNotTaxableAllExec, ISNULL(SumExe.SumTaxInsideExec + SumExe.SumTaxOutsideExec, 0) AS SumTaxAllExec, 
                     ISNULL(SumExe.SumWithoutTaxInsideExec + SumExe.SumWithoutTaxOutsideExec, 0) AS SumWithoutTaxAllExec, v.BalanceOrganization, v.BalanceDapartament, s.Note
FROM            dbo.ViewSumExecutorsOfStage AS SumExe INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Stages AS s ON SumExe.IdStage = s.IdStage RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.ViewBalanceOrgAndDepart AS v ON s.IdStage = v.IdStage
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои подходы к написанию результирующего запроса:

**1) Попытка сгруппировать строки из предыдущей выборки по IdStructure и просуммировать поля. В этом случае получаю итог по орг. структуре. но не учитывается вложенность отделов внутри организации.**

**(dbo.View_BalanceStage AS s)**

```
SELECT        dbo.Employees.IdStructure, ISNULL(SUM(s.PriceWithTax), 0) AS TotalPriceWithTax, ISNULL(SUM(s.PriceNotTaxable), 0) AS TotalNotTaxableCost, ISNULL(SUM(s.Tax), 0) AS TotalTax, ISNULL(SUM(s.PriceWithoutTax), 0) 
                     AS TotalWithoutTaxCost, ISNULL(SUM(s.TravelCosts), 0) AS TotalTravelCosts, ISNULL(SUM(s.MaterialCosts), 0) AS TotalMaterialCosts, ISNULL(SUM(s.OtherDirectCosts), 0) AS TotalOtherDirectCosts, 
                     ISNULL(SUM(s.SumOutsideExec), 0) AS TotalOutsideExecutorsCost, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumNotTaxableOutsideExec), 0) AS TotalNotTaxableOutsideExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumTaxOutsideExec), 0) AS TotalTaxOutExec, 
                     ISNULL(SUM(s.SumWithoutTaxOutsideExec), 0) AS TotalWithoutTaxOutsideExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumInsideExec), 0) AS TotalInsideExecutorsCost, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumNotTaxableInsideExec), 0) AS TotalNotTaxableInsideExec, 
                     ISNULL(SUM(s.SumTaxInsideExec), 0) AS TotalTaxInsideExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumWithoutTaxInsideExec), 0) AS TotalWithoutTaxInsideExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumAllExec), 0) AS TotalAllExec, 
                     ISNULL(SUM(s.SumNotTaxableAllExec), 0) AS TotalSumNotTaxableAllExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumTaxAllExec), 0) AS TotalSumTaxAllExec, ISNULL(SUM(s.SumWithoutTaxAllExec), 0) AS TotalSumWithoutTaxAllExec, 
                     ISNULL(SUM(s.BalanceOrganization), 0) AS TotalBalanceOrganization, ISNULL(SUM(s.BalanceDapartament), 0) AS TotalBalanceDapartament, ISNULL(SUM(s.BalanceOrganization), 0) AS AllBalanceOrganization
FROM            dbo.Contracts LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.Employees ON dbo.Contracts.IdManager = dbo.Employees.ldEmployee RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.View_BalanceStage AS s ON dbo.Contracts.IdContract = s.IdContract
GROUP BY dbo.Employees.IdStructure
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2) Написание запросов на определение всех вложенных структур:**

```
WITH Rec AS (
select IdStructure,IdStructure as IdStructurex, Title
from OrganizationalStructure
union all
select K.IdStructure, Rec.IdStructurex as IdStructurex, Rec.Title
from OrganizationalStructure K, Rec
where K.IdParentStruct=Rec.IdStructure 
)
select IdStructurex,IdStructure, Title from Rec
group by IdStructurex,IdStructure, Title
order by IdStructurex
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы же понимаете что такие большие запросы как минимум надо отлаживать. Я сомневаюсь что найдется много желающих во всем этом разбираться при том, что итоговая цель не понятна. Если же кто то догадается, чего вы хотите, то у него не будет ни малейшего желания убивать 2 часа на перебивание примеров заполнения таблиц с картинок, что бы попробовать запросы

Comment: @Mike Готовый ответ не требуется, прошу пояснить какими подходами можно просуммировать данные из одной таблицы с учетом  иерархической вложенности отделов. (каджый договор закреплен за отделом, а отделы группируются в более крупные орг. структуры - моя цель написать запрос, который в зависимости от уровня, будет суммировать по отделам(уровень 0), по управлению (уровень 1) или по всей организации (2). Не понятно как написать такого плана рекурсивный запрос... ) Если картинки и мои наработки смущают, могу их и убрать из вопроса.

Comment: Если нужна сумма вместе с детьми, то в своем рекурсивном запросе в первой части уберите условие на стартовый раздел. Так же добавьте поле с отделом в первой части, которое в рекурсивной части будет браться именно из рекурсивной записи, а не из текущей (Т.е. Rec.X). тогда на выходе вы получите выборку где будет отдел и все его подотделы и что важно в этом отдельном поле будет отдел с которого началась эта ветвь. вот по этой выборке уже и делаете суммирование, т.е. уже после With. ну и там же фильтруете ненужные ветки

Comment: @Mike "Так же добавьте поле с отделом в первой части, которое в рекурсивной части будет браться именно из рекурсивной записи, а не из текущей (Т.е. Rec.X)"  - я наверное не очень Вас хорошо поняла, под полем отдела подразумевается IdStructure?

Comment: @Mike Я понимаю, что указание Where тут не нужно, но как только его убираю - получается ерунда

Comment: Там получается не ерунда, а вполне разумные записи, которые при этом невозможно понять без указания какая из ветвей рекурсии реально породила эту строку. А это как раз можно понять добавив такое поле. Вот например тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481272/194569 добавлялся id записи, под именем idx. И да, я думаю это поле idStructure

Comment: @Mike отредактировала вопрос, по этой части я поняла Ваш комментарий. Попробую объединить наработки