# Подсчитать сумму всех значений подчиненных строк

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Из таблицы SQL php принимает id, parent, name, value. Как для каждого элемента вывести sum, которая равна свой value + value подчиненных? Где проще это сделать, в SQL и потом передать значения sum в php, или все считать в php?

Comment: Если у вас 8 mysql или практически любая другая СУБД, то это  делается простым запросом. Но если у вас именно mysql и до 8 версии, то лучше в php.

Comment: mysql 8 стоит, и что за простой запрос такой?

Comment: ну ладно, может не совсем простой, что нибудь такое, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481261/194569  только count() на сумму по нужному полю заменить

Comment: достаточно просто и элегантно, однако не совсем понял по какой логике работает sql, находя все вложения, на php был бы достаточно объемный код с циклом в цикле и кучей условий

Comment: Основная часть, которая после union all, у нее в запросе есть в качестве таблицы сама выборка `q`. Первый раз запрос получает в `q` то что выбрала первая часть, а потом он опять повторяется но в `q` оказывается то, что он только что сам выбрал. тут главное вовремя остановится :) но с join особых проблем с остановкой нет, приклеивать больше нечего, выбирать нечего, в q больше ничего не добавляется

Comment: Вообще, при вложенности один можно\нужно просто джонить таблицу на себя с последующей группировкой. А при вложенности два - джонить два раза. При большей вложенности стоит подумать над необходимостью хранить данные таким образом в реляционной БД.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов В принципе они и так хранятся в нормальном для реляционной БД виде. А более одного join не нужно, потому что именно это выполняет рекурсивный запрос для любого уровня вложенности. (Nurk33RUS, кстати, возможно стоит рекурсию представить себе именно так (автоматический join для каждого уровня вложенности), что бы осмыслить как именно работает тот запрос)